# gdal_translate to get full vector extent of geo spatial referenced PDF

Tags: grids-graticules, gdal-translate, geopdf

I am creating GeoTif images from a USFS geospatial referenced PDFs using gdal_translate. I turned off all of the layers that I did not want and it produces a GeoTif of just the center window of the PDF. The graticule layer seems to define this.

Using QGIS, I load the PDF as a vector layer (all layers are not listed which is another question). QGIS clearly draws features that extend beyond the graticule layer. This is the PDF.

http://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/rastergateway/data/36081/fstopo/362208152_Doe_FSTopo.pdf

Is there a way that gdal_translate can produce a GeoTif of this extra information that lies outside of the graticule layer?